# Javascript condition assign value to data variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am reading some data from the database which are numbers.

What I need to do is to assign a name to each number ...

something like:

```
get the variable: ... thevar = '1';

If thevar = 1 then myname = 'name1';
else
If thevar = 2 then myname = 'name2';
```

How can I do this with javascript?

Sorry, I don't think I've explained it properly...what I need if the syntax on how I would do this the above with javascript.

Hope it now makes more sense.

Comment: `myname = 'name' + myvariable`?

Comment: I still have no idea what the question is. Did ChaosPandion get it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about `myname = 'name' + myvariable;`

Assuming you want the syntax of w.e you have posted,

```
var thevar = '1'; //read from database
var myname = '';

if (thevar === '1') {
  myname = 'name1';
} else if (thevar === '2') {
  myname = 'name2';
}
```

Comment: @Satch3000 Updated answer.. not sure if that is what you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can concatenate numbers and strings in JavaScript:

```
myname = 'name' + myvariable
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function buildNumberMap(numbers) {
    var i, len, number, map = {};
    for (i = 0, len = numbers.length; i < len; i++) {
        number = numbers[i];
        map["name" + number] = number;
    }
    return map;
}
```